# What is the maximum length of a filename (APFS)?

Tags: macos, mac, filesystems, filenames

Last weekend I saved a file with a quite long name (some 40 - 50 characters). This got me wondering what the maximum length is of a file name on Mac? This would (presumably) also include the extension and the dot.

Comment: A reasonable research effort would be to try to reach some limit in a scratch (or any) APFS filesystem. There may be other factors or limitations that can affect the result; simple experiments will not reveal these connections. Therefore asking for an answer based on specifications and insight is justified. Still in general we expect any question to show some research effort and in this case such experiment may be exactly this. So… What have you done to investigate? What does the limit in *your* filesystem seem to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Comparison of filesystems article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits), the maximum length of a file name in APFS is 255 UTF-8 characters.

Comment: It would be great if this answer included some more details. What is a UTF-8 character? A codepoint?

Comment: The wikipedia article itself does not specify any details, but my guess would be "code units" aka bytes.